# Datatables class selected

Tags: jquery, datatable, addclass

I would like to add class to selected row, when I initialize table and click on row my code is working well.

```
 $('#dataTables-example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {            
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) { 
            $(this).removeClass('selected'); 
        } 
        else {                 
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected'); 
            console.log($(this).text());
            $(this).addClass('selected').css('color', 'red');                
        }  

      });
```

But when I reinitialize table by Ajax and click on new row adding class 'selected' is not working.

Comment: `.css('color', 'red')` working, but `addClass` not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `off('click', 'tr')` helped.

```
$('#dataTables-example tbody').off('click', 'tr').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {            
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) { 
        $(this).removeClass('selected'); 
    } 
    else {                 
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected'); 
        console.log($(this).text());
        $(this).addClass('selected').css('color', 'red');                
    }  

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(function() {
      $('#dataTables-example tbody tr').click(function() {
        $('#dataTables-example tbody tr').removeClass('selected');
        var el = $(this);
        el.addClass('selected');
      })

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a syntax error here:

```
table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

which should be:

```
table.find('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

You need to find the `tr` element with the class name `selected` if it has then remove the class name from it.

Comment: var table I have inicialized before this:

Comment: @user3041678 Okay then you can try this `table.find('tr.selected').removeClass('selected'); `

Comment: OK, but removing class workign well, adding class selected to row in new table is not working `$(this).addClass('selected').css('color', 'red');`